# Formatting dataframe column values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {
  "txt": ['12 MG/0.6 ML  8 MG/0.4 ML  12.5 MG  25 MG  39.5%  20%  550 MG  75 MG  800 MG  9 MG  75 MG/0.5 ML  0.03%  0.10%  1%  2% 0.50%', '12 MG/0.6 ML ]
}
```

I want to do a couple things here:

1. Add space between the decimal number and % sign. for example 39.5% should become 39.5 %. This is easy with a simple replace.
2. If the decimal number is something like 0.10% then I need it to become 0.1 % i.e. the second decimal place gone if it is a zero in that place and then add the space ( the space part is easy replace after 2 is done).
   3.I need to apply this update in the dataframe column df['txt'] itself, meaning the expected output is:

```
data = {
  "txt": ['12 MG/0.6 ML  8 MG/0.4 ML  12.5 MG  25 MG  39.5 %  20 %  550 MG  75 MG  800 MG  9 MG  75 MG/0.5 ML  0.03 %  0.1 %  1 %  2 % 0.5 %', '12 MG/0.6 ML ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

- first find the numbers with percentages and convert it to float
- use these floats and do a string formatting where you remove trailing zeros

```py
import re

s = "12 MG/0.6 ML  8 MG/0.4 ML  12.5 MG  25 MG  39.5%  20%  550 MG  75 MG  800 MG  9 MG  75 MG/0.5 ML  0.03%  0.1%  1%  2%"

out = list(map(float, re.findall(r"(\d*[,.]?\d*)%", s)))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[39.5, 20.0, 0.03, 0.1, 1.0, 2.0]
```

Then remove trailing zeros:

```
out = list(map("{:g} %".format, out))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['39.5 %', '20 %', '0.03 %', '0.1 %', '1 %', '2 %']
```

---

EDIT: With updated input:

```py
import re

data = {
    "txt": [
        "12 MG/0.6 ML  8 MG/0.4 ML  12.5 MG  25 MG  39.5%  20%  550 MG  75 MG  800 MG  9 MG  75 MG/0.5 ML  0.03%  0.10%  1%  2% 0.50%",
        "12 MG/0.6 ML",
    ]
}

out = []
for line in data["txt"]:
    out.append(re.sub(r"(\d*[,.]?\d*)%", lambda g: f"{float(g.group(1)):g} %", line))

data["txt"] = out
print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "txt": [
        "12 MG/0.6 ML  8 MG/0.4 ML  12.5 MG  25 MG  39.5 %  20 %  550 MG  75 MG  800 MG  9 MG  75 MG/0.5 ML  0.03 %  0.1 %  1 %  2 % 0.5 %",
        "12 MG/0.6 ML",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej.  This is what I have so far

Comment: Thanks Andrej! This is what I have so far:  
import re
import pandas as pd
import sys

data = [['12 MG/0.6 ML  8 MG/0.4 ML  12.5 MG  25 MG  39.50%  20%  550 MG  75 MG  800 MG  9 MG  75 MG/0.5 ML  0.03%  0.1%  1%  2%'], 
        ['12 MG/0.6 ML ']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['txt'])
try:
    for i, j in df.iterrows():
        #print( j['txt'])
        out = list(map(float, re.findall(r"(\d*[,.]?\d*)%", j['txt'])))
        out = list(map("{:g} %".format, out))

        for i in out:
            print(i)
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print(  e.args() )

Comment: I would like to write the changes to the original dataframe. But this gives a separate list called out. Is there a way to 1. either write it back to the dataframe with the other contents as is? 2. Do in place updates?

Comment: @user22407116 Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76924627/edit) your question and put the sample input and expected output there (in text form)?

Comment: I have updated the question and added expected output. Thanks for your help so far!